# What was the need to create different processor architectures?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I have been studying processors for a while and I found out that there are a lot of processor architectures available. Once we got a working processor architecture, why did we create other architectures?

I understand that we had to create better architectures. But, A specific architecture is going to execute a task in a certain fashion. So, what could be the drawbacks in a certain architecture that had to be fulfilled by another(better) one?

Comment: To make _better_ architectures? (Why is there more than one programming language and more than one text editor?)

Comment: @user1686 yes, indeed. A specific architecture is going to execute a task in a certain fashion. So, what could be the drawbacks in a certain architecture that had to be fulfilled by another one?

Comment: There are too many reasons and a lot of them are beyond things to do with how programs work. Many of them are economic and being the sole supplier of a particular architecture can have massive benefits in terms of licencing royalties alone. Case in point, ARM is an intellectual property company that licences CPU core designs and has no actual manufacturing facilities. Other reasons could be target markets: ARM has typically aimed at the low power embedded markets while Intel has targeted high performance home and work computing. Other companies may lean further in either direction.

Answer (score 3):

The goal of creating a processor architecture is to make a fast processor. Research will allow to discover techniques to make a processor faster, and the architecture is the design behind where different components are.

The problem is that at a certain point, the current architecture just cannot get any faster processors. Given that there are more than one manufacturers that create processors, at some point if you don't look for other ways to get a faster processor (and thus change the architecture) the competition will create faster processors and as a result your clients will stop shopping for your products and go away.

So you have to innovate in order to stay in business. If your current architecture cannot get the same speeds as your competition, then you have to change the architecture to something that can.

When you see that the competition changes architecture too in order to get a much improved speed gain, you know this is the path you have to take too in order to stay in the race to create the fastest processor.

Comment: The objective is not always speed. Low power consumption can be very important for computers used in battery-powered equipment. Like any piece of engineering, an architecture is a compromise.